# Share credentials with cross domain script tag in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, cross-domain

Suppose I've authorized in domain `boo.com` already and have this session:

```
s:x2GYrvxGgmsfFwx7gDbKXmwB.4BDXLpMaSqD9hgeTkBDx3z4TeczJeC50gnrH5bc+kWU
```

What I want is to add a script tag to domain `foo.com`, points to `boo.com`:

```
<script src='http://boo.com/blah.js'></script>
```

In all browsers including Safari and Google Chrome, the script tag sets the cookie value in HTTP headers but it doesn't work in Firefox.

Firefox doesn't set the cookie headers so I get `Unauthorized` error from server. What is the problem?

**UPDATE:**

I enabled CORS in server-side but the problem is still exist in Firefox:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://foo.com');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Cookie');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

Comment: I recreated the situation you described but [could not reproduce the problem](http://note.io/1jYCcUI).

Comment: @Quentin Can I know you Firefox version?

Comment: @Quentin Can you please let me know `network.cookie.thirdparty.sessionOnly` value of your Firefox? Is that `true` or `false`?

Comment: It is `false`, but that is the default value. The cookie is a session cookie though, so requiring session cookies wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Quentin It's a session cookie in my case. Ok, thanks. Please let me know update the question with screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Because my Firefox doesn't accept third-party cookie, the `script` tag and all other http requests from another domain don't share the cookie.

[image: Here is the setting in Firefox]

[image: The option was <code>Never</code> before]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
<script src="http://boo.com/blah.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Read more here:
http://blog.errorception.com/2012/12/catching-cross-domain-js-errors.html

Comment: That attribute enables greater error reporting. It doesn't appear to deal with the problem in the question at all.

Comment: @Quentin I think the answer is a little bit incomplete, I should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in response headers also. What do you think?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani — It isn't incomplete, it is entirely wrong. Setting CORS headers won't help, it isn't a Same Origin Policy violation and you aren't using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Quentin Weird. Did you read this post: http://blog.errorception.com/2012/12/catching-cross-domain-js-errors.html

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani — Yes, I did. Look at the first paragraph of that blog entry. The attribute is all about exposing more detailed error objects when an exception is thrown. It has nothing to do with allowing cookies. The word "cookie" is not used on that page at all, nor is it used in the [specification for the attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-crossorigin).